# zsh autocomplete working for commands but not branch names

Tags: git, autocomplete, zsh

I have [git-completion.zsh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh) installed in `~/.zsh/_git` and `fpath=(~/.zsh $fpath)` in `~/.zshrc`.

On a local checkout with (among others) a `master` branch:

- With `git check<tab>` I get `git checkout`
- With `git checkout mas<tab>` (and repeated `<tab>`s) I get nothing: just `git checkout mas`

System:

- Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Zsh 5.4.2 (x86_64-debian-linux-gnu)
- Git 2.17.0.rc0.231.g781580f06

Comment: It is possible that the branch may not have a local copy. Try `git fetch` and then the tab. Have you tried the autocomplete on branches you already have locally?

Comment: AFAICT that's not the issue. This is a project I've been working on for a while, freshly `git pull`ed